# Get JobDetail by string job name

Tags: c#, .net, quartz.net

How to get IJobDetail if I only have string job name, not JobKey?

```
string jobName
```

I have access to

```
public IScheduler Scheduler { get; set; }
```

object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
Quartz.Collection.ISet<JobKey> jobKeys = scheduler.GetJobKeys(GroupMatcher<JobKey>.GroupEquals(SchedulerConstants.DefaultGroup));
jobKeys.Where(key => key.Name == "Your job name")
```

Comment: Added following components to get this to work:
using Quartz.Impl.Matchers;
using Quartz.Collection;
However ISet does not contain definition for 'Where'? What component need to add to enable this extension for ISet?

Comment: Where works only with ISet from System.Collections.Generic, not from Quartz.Collection.

Comment: Are you sure? I took that from a code I wrote which is working

Comment: Yeah, sorry, strange it did not work for me in the first time. Thanks, this works.

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing, following works:

```
using Quartz;
using Quartz.Impl.Matchers;
using Quartz.Collection;
using System.Linq;


ISet<JobKey> jobKeys = _scheduler.GetJobKeys(GroupMatcher<JobKey>.GroupEquals(SchedulerConstants.DefaultGroup));
JobKey key = jobKeys.Where(x => x.Name == jobName).First();
IJobDetail jobData = _scheduler.GetJobDetail(key);
```